# get the cell containing a specific data in appscript

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a follow up of unpaid invoices.

For that I'd like to find a way to get to the cell of a specified invoice number.

For example, I need to go the cell containing 6126944 in the column H in the sheet follow up

This number will always be typed in the cell D16,  of the sheet "first call".

Is there any way to do that, I'm quite new on appscript

Comment: *get the cell*, *go to the cell* -- do you mean to jump to this cell? There is the method `activate()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()

Answer (score 2):

If you need just to jump to the next sheet cell (column H) that contains the same number as the cell D16 -- here is the way:

```
function jump_to_cell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet_first_call = ss.getSheetByName('First call');
  var sheet_follow_up = ss.getSheetByName('Follow up');

  var num = sheet_first_call.getRange('D16').getValue();
  var nums = sheet_follow_up.getRange('H:H').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  for (var row in nums) {
    if (nums[row] == num) {
      sheet_follow_up.getRange('H'+(row+1)).activate();
      break;
    }
  }

}
```